# WebAudio API - Get audio data from an AudioNode

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Given an `AudioNode`, is there any way to directly get the audio data from it? The data could be an `ArrayBuffer`, an `AudioBuffer`, a `TypedArray` or something similar.

I don't want to use any kind of Media Stream stuff.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode

Answer (score -1):

Connect a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` to the output of the node you're interested in.  These will give you buffers of audio data.  You'll have to figure out how and where to save all the data, but these nodes will give you the audio data.  If you can, use `AudioWorkletNode`, which isn't subject to main thread loading issues.